# SKLabelNode will disappear but is still clickable

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I am making a game using SpriteKit and Swift, running Xcode 6. I have an `SKLabelNode`, let's call it `myLabelNode` for this example. When I call `myLabelNode.removeFromParent()` it removes the node from the scene, as it should. The node count drops by 1, and it isn't visible anywhere on the screen. However, when I click the spot where `myLabelNode` previously was, my program will still call out the function that should only happen when `myLabelNode` is touched. I also tried combining `myLabelNode.removeFromParent()` with `myLabelNode.hidden = true`, but it is still touchable, and calls the function even though it shouldn't. How should I fix this? Is there a different method I should be using? Is this supposed to happen?

Edit:

```
    let lemonadeLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Optima-ExtraBlack")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    lemonadeLabel.text = "Lemonade Stand"
    lemonadeLabel.fontSize = 24
    lemonadeLabel.fontColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    lemonadeLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height*0.66)
    lemonadeLabel.zPosition = 2.0
    addChild(lemonadeLabel)

    }


    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if lemonadeLabel.containsPoint(location) {

            println("lemonadeLabel pressed")
            lemonadeLabel.removeFromParent()
            /*lemonadeLabel is now be removed,
            however if I click the area where it 
            used to be, "lemonadeLabel pressed"
            will print to the console*/

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could we see the code to be in a better position to help?

Comment: @Tokuriku Here it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to determine if the constrainPoints' location are being touched. Even if you remove the label from the scene, it is still an object in memory, i.e: you could re-ad it later.. it still has all it's properties including position, etc..

I would try this instead:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        if nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) == lemonadeLabel {
            println("lemonadeLabel pressed")
            lemonadeLabel.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

You basically determine if the lemonadeLabel is the node at that position, if yes you remove it. Since you compare with the added node in the scene, if it's gone, it will not be there for comparison ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `labelNode` may not be inside the `SKScene` anymore. This does not mean that it will not respond to the `containsPoint` function. The `labelNode` still has a position assigned to it and it can calculate if a point falls inside it using `containsPoint` function.

Instead you can try this.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if self.nodeAtPoint(location) === lemonadeLabel {

        println("lemonadeLabel pressed")
        lemonadeLabel.removeFromParent()

    }

}
```